# The field which allows user to enter only the string which is already in database by selection from the dropdown list

Tags: android, layout, drop-down-menu, tags, uitextfield

I want to use such a field in android which will allow user to select from the drop down list and enter only those values which are in list (like a drop down list).

Menu of this list changes when user edit the text in field. And the user should also be able to enter more than one value Like in image below.

[image: Refer this image]

I want to do totally like in the image in which data will be retrieved from database by changing the text and user can only add those values which are in database already.

Is it possible to do in android??

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Comment: you can use AutoCompleteTextView for that Here's a pretty straightforward solution: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394054/android-restrict-user-to-select-from-autocompletion-textview-only)