# How to Disable free text in AutoCompleteTextView Android

Tags: android, adapter, edit, autocompletetextview

In my Androdi App, i am using a AutoCompleteTextView. Iam using ArrayAdapter to set the suggestions. Now, I want the user to select only from the suggestions dropdown and not allow the user to input any free text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Restrict user from selecting other than autocompletion suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394054/android-restrict-user-from-selecting-other-than-autocompletion-suggestions)

Comment: Alternative: What about using a spinner? That's the main function of that element.

Comment: @javdromero Unfortunately Material Components for Android seems to have forgotten about spinners and wants you to use non-editable [exposed dropdown menus](https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use FocussableInTouchMode as false and cursorVisibile as false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

`android:inputType="none"`